# Differential equation notation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$(x^2D^2-3xD+4I)y=0$$ where $$y(1)=-\pi$$
$$y'(1)=2\pi$$

I want to ask what does D and I mean? I found that D denotes $\frac {d}{dx}$

But what about I? Can anyone help me?

Does it become $x^2y''-3xy'+4y=0$ ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: $I$ stands for the identity operator and yes, that is the differential equation, an Euler-Cauchy equation.

Comment: I is the identity.  I y = y.

Answer (score 0):

In order to explain this notation *intuitively*, you need to have a particular perspective on what a differential operator is.

One can think of the differentiation as a "function" (we generally call it an operator) that given a differentiable function, provides another function "differentiated" with respect to some variables.

We can denote $\mathcal{D}$ a differential operator, say for example, that $\mathcal{D}$ acts like $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$, or $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x\partial y}$, or else...

Given two differentiable functions $f,g$ and a scalar $\alpha$, we usually have the following properties:
$$\begin{aligned}\mathcal{D}(f+g)&=\mathcal{D}(f)+\mathcal{D}(g)\\
\mathcal{D}(\alpha f)&=\alpha \mathcal{D}(f)\end{aligned}$$

Meaning the operator $\mathcal{D}$ is linear.

Now take two functions $a,b$. One day, you might want to do something like:
$$(a\circ\mathcal{D}+b)(f)=a\circ\mathcal{D}(f)+b(f)= \dots$$

But as you can see, the notation is a bit heavy... And you might want to be more straightforward.

You also know how in finite dimension, a linear map can be viewed as a matrix ? Where one can add, multiply etc... matrices together as a way to manipulate the underlying linear maps. If you consider a differentiable function $f$ to be a *vector of infinite size*, then, $\mathcal{D}$ being a linear map, it can be seen as a *matrix of infinite size* as well.

$$\mathcal{D}(f)=g \longleftrightarrow Df=g \longleftrightarrow Ax=b$$

I hope this explains in a clear way why this notation makes sense:

$$\begin{aligned}(a\circ\mathcal{D}\circ\mathcal{D}+b\circ\mathcal{D}+4Id)(y)=0 &\longleftrightarrow (x^2D^2-3xD+4I)y=0 \\
&\longleftrightarrow x^2y''-3xy'+4y=0 \end{aligned}$$

With $(a(f))(x)=x^2 \times f(x)$ and $(b(f))(x) = -3x \times f(x)$ and $\mathcal{D}$ acting like $\frac{d}{dx}$.